# SharePoint 2010 - Jquery - Installed on Server

Tags: list, jquery, column

My company has jquery installed on every SharePoint, and while I have years of SP experience including design, very new to jquery.

My problem is I need to use a jquery solution to freeze the header/column on a list.

But every solution I see has something like this at the beginning of the code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have changed my table name and inserted my GUID....
the only thing I can think it is I need to modify the above line because it shouldn't have to go anywhere to find it?

Let the flogging commence!~ :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above the script you posted loads jquery to your page so you can use its function but, since you mentioned about freezing headers 
[Check here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a617abcf-628d-428d-a680-244edb909a4b/sharepoint-2013-list-header-row-freeze?forum=sharepointdevelopment) to know how would you implement them, alternatively there is a script which makes this possible in easier way [click here](http://spoodoo.com/sticky-headers-in-sharepoint-2013/) for more details

Comment: Apparently I am missing SOMETHING.....I have tried all of these solutions, inserted code in advanced mode on the page, in content editor and in HTML form web parts.  No errors....and nothing on the page changes.   I have even downloaded js to my site assets and pointed the script there...  The banging of head against my cubicle wall is about to commence!~

Comment: did check this the script is updated, you have to out this script in master page I assume you are using SP2013  http://spoodoo.com/sticky-headers-sharepoint-2013-v2-0/

Answer (score 0):

The added script tag is to load the JQuery plugin. After loading it you have to explicitly write your JQuery code to hide the elements, either by using class name or the control id.

**Example:**
The below code snippet will be executed after page load and hides a control.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#ControlID').hide()
});
```